I cannot get form-data data with Laravel PATCH and PUT methods
I cannot get form-data data with Laravel PATCH and PUT methods. I can get form-data data with POST method, with PUT and PATCH form-data data comes empty.
 public function update(Request $request, string $id)
 {
    $data = $request->all();
    dd($data);
 }


How can I get form-data data with PUT AND PATCH methods?

Check your routes

I use API resources.
Route::apiResource('poets', PoetController::class);

try adding _method key and PATCH value in form-data

Yes, this is how I solved my problem.

Ok accept the answer so that this question can be closed

This question is similar to: PATCH and PUT Request Does not Working with form-data. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Add key:_method and value:PATCH in form-data
